# Switch desktops hotkey on Windows is not ignored by Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

The following keys:

- `Ctrl-Win-Left`
- `Ctrl-Win-Right`

are used to switch desktops on Windows.

If Emacs is the active window when you use either of these keys, you get the following in the minibuffer:

[image]

If you're using `emacsclient`, you may also have the taskbar icon flashing until you switch to that window:

[image]

One approach that seems to work to resolve this is adding the following to the init file:

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (global-set-key (kbd "<C-lwindow>") 'ignore))
```

Is that the recommended approach for resolving this?

Is this issue considered a bug for Emacs on Windows? Should the above ignore-behaviour be the default?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? (I don't.)

If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

With `emacs -Q` on MS Windows 10, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> (right arrow) is `<C-M-right>`, and it can be bound or unbound normally. It's bound by default to command `forward-sexp`.

And with `emacs -Q`, `<C-lwindow>` is available and unbound by default.

---

**UPDATED after your edit:**

Try putting this in your init file:

```lisp
(w32-register-hot-key (kbd "<C-lwindow>"))
(w32-register-hot-key (kbd "<C-rwindow>"))
```

Or maybe something like this (see doc below), to be able to bind only the left window key for Emacs:

```lisp
(setq w32-lwindow-modifier 'super)
(register-hot-key [s-])
```

`C-h f w32-register-hot-key` tells us:

> **`w32-register-hot-key`** is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(w32-register-hot-key KEY)`
>
> Register `KEY` as a hot-key combination.
>
> Certain key combinations like `Alt-Tab` and `Win-R` are reserved for
> system use on Windows, and therefore are normally intercepted by the
> system.  These key combinations can be received by registering them
> as hot-keys, except for `Win-L` which always locks the computer.
>
> On Windows 98 and ME, `KEY` must be a one element key definition in
> vector form that would be acceptable to `define-key` (e.g. `[A-tab]` for
> `Alt-Tab`).  The meta modifier is interpreted as `Alt` if
> `w32-alt-is-meta` is `t`, and `hyper` is always interpreted as the Windows
> modifier keys.  The return value is the hotkey-id if registered, otherwise `nil`.
>
> On Windows versions since NT, `KEY` can also be specified as `[M-]`, `[s-]` or
> `[h-]` to indicate that all combinations of that key should be processed
> by Emacs instead of the operating system.  The `super` and `hyper`
> modifiers are interpreted according to the current values of
> `w32-lwindow-modifier` and `w32-rwindow-modifier`.  For instance,
> setting `w32-lwindow-modifier` to `super` and then calling
> `(register-hot-key [s-])` grabs all combinations of the left Windows
> key to Emacs, but leaves the right Windows key free for the operating
> system keyboard shortcuts.  The return value is `t` if the call affected
> any key combinations, otherwise `nil`.

Comment: Hey Drew! Sorry, I meant `Ctrl-Win-Left` and `Ctrl-Win-Right`.

Yes, I just tried again with `emacs -Q` and the effect is there.

This is on `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2020-08-21`

Comment: Hey Drew! The `(w32-register-hot-key (kbd "<C-lwindow>"))` approach does not seem to work on my system. I get the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will have a suggestion that helps.

Comment: Well, the approach  I posted in the question  is working  ok. Just wanted to see if that's the recommended solution and if it's a known issue. Thanks for looking at it!